# Linq to xml: how do I get subset of elements after performing remove()

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq-to-xml

If I have code like this (C# or VB.Net does not matter)

```
  Dim e As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
            From s In _dataSourceSettings.Elements _
            Where s.Attribute("name").Value = toInsert.Attribute("name").Value
        If e.Count > 0 Then
            e.Remove()
        End If
```

How do I get now new _dataSourceSettings without element that I removed?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, nevermind it is already without that node